# Case( select) when then

Tags: sql

The query is compiled correctly. Prompt how to make correctly. You need to get three variables and check them out. Depending on the selected test date.

after when is not written correctly

```
select sum(t.sum),t3.cost, t.status 
from  Credit t inner join  cost t3 on t.code= t3.code1
where  t.id='1' and 
t.date >= case (SELECT t1.mark1, t1.mark2, t2.mark3
                FROM marks t1 INNER JOIN marksagain t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
                WHERE t1.id = t.id)
          when (0,0,6) then (INTNX('month',date(),6,'same')) 
          else(INTNX('month',date(),3,'same')) end
group by t.sum, t3.cost, t.status;`
```

Comment: there is no 'WHEN' after 'CASE'. You need a condition in your WHEN.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Searching on `INTNX`, a function I didn't recognize, suggests that this may be `sas` related. But we shouldn't *have* to guess. Please [edit] in the appropriate tags (that you were already strongly suggested to do when you added the `sql` tag)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: there was a `sas-ds2` tag at the beginning. But the tag description didn't indicate that that was an actual database product so I removed it (as the question only shows SQL)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
select sum(t.sum),t3.cost, t.status
            from  Credit t inner join  cost t3 on t.code= t3.code1
    where  t.id='1' and t.date >=
        case when (SELECT t1.mark1 FROM marks t1 INNER JOIN marksagain t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = t.id) = 0
                AND (SELECT t1.mark2 FROM marks t1 INNER JOIN marksagain t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = t.id) = 0
                AND (SELECT t2.mark3 FROM marks t1 INNER JOIN marksagain t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) WHERE t1.id = t.id) = 6
        then (INTNX('month',date(),6,'same')) else(INTNX('month',date(),3,'same'))
        end
    group by t.sum, t3.cost, t.status;
```

Comment: No problem, mark it as answer. would be helpful to others